How to simplify the LLVM-IR generated by remill?
I tried using remill to lift a function from a .exe file. Unfortunately, based on the official example provided. It resulted in completely unreadable IR function. Result looks like being inflated by VMP.. I tried O2 optimize, however, has no use. I can't find any remill api to do the task.
What is the proper way to use remill? I got a output from remill::TraceLifter. What to do next to simplify the output (or make them closer to the original ASM function) ?

IR is generally quite different from the original function. The original function is written in a language intended for humans to edit, IR is a kind of language whose only major goal is being easy to operate on by simple function (called passes in LLVM). There's much positive to say about IR, but readability isn't on the list.

I mean, asm functions, I tried to lift asm functions to LLVM-IR. I thought the output IR should be looks like the original asm functions, but the output looks like a VM. For example, mov rax, 0 is lifted to state.rax = 0. I thought it should be %1 = 0.
Anyway, thank for your reply :)

%1 is just the name of a value, %state.rax is another name. Many IR generators use numerical names because that's simplest, other try to pick names that relate somehow to the source, as this generator does,
